# Converting double to string and then place on a label and the label needs to change value depending on where trackbar is moved to

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to get the answer to a calculation, i have a trackbar and what ever number the track bar is left on the number is divided under 1 and then printer out onto the label.

```
private void label29_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            double x1;

            String fnum;
            x1 = 1 / trackBar1.Value;

            fnum = x1.ToString();

            label29 = fnum;


        }
```

I am getting an error saying Error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label"

Comment: you have to specify the text property of the label :
label29.Text = fnum;

Comment: You should use `label29.Text = fnum;`

Comment: The label doesn't change, it still shows the standard "labe29"

Comment: call  label29.refresh()  ?

Comment: Please note that `trackBar1.Value` returns `int`, so `1 / trackBar1.Value;` can be `0`, `1` or `Division by zero!` exception. Try `label29.Text = (1.0 / trackBar1.Value).ToString();` instead of your all code in `label29_Click` event.

Comment: Thanks i included @SiyavashHamdi last method and it works smoothly